# How to get html tags from url?

Tags: python, html, url, printing

How would you get all the `HTML` tags from a `URL` and print them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib
print urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/blah').read()
```

Comment: Some sites use compression, and this fails miserably when they do. It took me *sooo* long to figure it out, but the workaround was really ugly. I'll post if I find it. +1

Comment: Those sites violating http spec then. Unless an appropriate Accept-encoding is sent the should not return compressed data.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch it (using `mechanize`, `urllib` or whatever else you want), parse what you get (using `elementtree`, `BeautifulSoup`, `lxml` or whatever else you want) and you have what you want.