# How to get html tags?

Tags: python

Say I have a text file like this:

```
<html><head>Headline<html><head>more words
</script>even more words</script>
<html><head>Headline<html><head>more words
</script>even more words</script>
```

How would I get just the tags into a list like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<html>
<head>
</script>
</script>
<html>
<head>
<html>
<head>
</script>
</script>
```

Comment: Is this a continuation of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435882/how-to-get-html-tags-from-url)? If it is, you should really edit your other question, rather than re-post

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you want:

```
html_string = ''.join(input_file.readlines())
matches = re.findall('<.*?>', html_string)
for m in matches:
    print m
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i think you mean: re.findall('<.*?>', html_string)

Comment: @JackNull: You're absolutely right. The extra double quotes are a typo and have been retro-actively fixed

Answer (score 4):

Python has a [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) module for this.

Here is some code which does what you want:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "<%s>"%tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "</%s>"%tag

parser = MyHTMLParser();
parser.feed("""<html><head>Headline<html><head>more words
        </script>even more words</script>
        <html><head>Headline<html><head>more words
        </script>even more words</script>
        """)
```

Enter your string in `parser.feed`

Output:

```
$ python htmlparser.py 
<html>
<head>
<html>
<head>
</script>
</script>
<html>
<head>
<html>
<head>
</script>
</script>
```

This discussion on SO should help: [Using HTMLParser in Python efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182521/using-htmlparser-in-python-efficiently)