# Django: Safely validating untrusted HTML input

Tags: html, django, xss

I want to purify user input in Django.

I know there is [Django Html Purifier](https://github.com/whitehat2k9/django-htmlpurifier) but maybe there is something lighter? What if the tags I'd like to allow users to use are very limited, e.g. just `<b>`? Maybe there is something built-in Django I could use?

Comment: thanks, I didn't know if it; I guess it's better than using Purifier as it's pure python

Comment: @RobertJ. I've ended up using Bleach, if you'd post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Django [recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.remove_tags) `bleach` : https://github.com/jsocol/bleach - (Note that django-bleach is a wrapper around bleach, to make it a Django app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`django-bleach` derived from a PHP implementation is commonly used.

The project is here: https://bitbucket.org/ionata/django-bleach

It's usage is really simple and according to the docs seems to do what you want:

```
# Which HTML tags are allowed
BLEACH_ALLOWED_TAGS = ['p', 'b', 'i', 'u', 'em', 'strong', 'a']
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Python has a [HTML Parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) for handling tags in a string. Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436008/how-to-get-html-tags) as well.

You can write something on top of this module for your use case. For example

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

VALID_TAGS = ['b', 'a', 'strong']

class ForbiddenHTMLException(Exception):
    pass

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag in VALID_TAGS:
            pass
        else:
            raise ForbiddenHTMLException

def validate(html):
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    try:
        parser.feed(html)
        return True
    except ForbiddenHTMLException:
        return False

print validate('<b>This is bold Text</b>')
print validate('<p>This is not inside b tag.</p>')
```

Comment: However I would have to implement my own parsing -- I don't want users not to be able to save the comment, I just want to get rid of potentially malicious tags.